# What does +? mean in regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have seen `+?` a lot in regex, but I'm not sure what it really stands for. I know `+` means `1` or more, and `?` means `0` or `1`. So does `+?` means `0` or more? In that case, why not just use `*`, which means `0` or more?

I just need to know if `+?` means `0` or more, or it means something different. Then I'll delete this question if it's too annoying.

Comment: It means "one or more" - preferably as few as possible (shortest match).

Comment: `?` has different meanings depending on where it appears. After a `+` or a `*` or another `?` it means “non-greedy”.

Comment: @jessica The duplicate targets have multiple examples, plus this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491947

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ? makes the + "lazy" instead of "greedy".  This means it tries to match as few times as possible, instead of trying to match as many times  as possible.