# Make dictionary from txt file using re

Tags: python, regex

Consider the standard web log file in assets/logdata.txt. This file records the access a user makes when visiting a web page (like this one!). Each line of the log has the following items:

- a host (e.g., `'146.204.224.152'`)
- a user_name (e.g., `'feest6811'` note: sometimes the user name is missing! In this case, use '-' as the value for the username.)
- the time a request was made (e.g., `'21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700'`)
- the post request type (e.g., `'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'` note: not everything is a POST!)

Your task is to convert this into a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary looks like the following:

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

This is sample of the txt data file.

[image: sample of the text file]

I wrote these lines of codes:

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        #print(logdata)
        pattern="""
        (?P<host>.*)        
        (-\s)   
        (?P<user_name>\w*)  
        (\s) 
        ([POST]*)
        (?P<time>\w*)               
                 """
        for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
            print(item.groupdict())
        return(item)
logs()
```

It helped my in making `"host"` and `"user_name"` however I can't continue and making the rest of the requirements. can anyone help please?
[image: this is what i have done till now]

Answer (score 5):

try this my friend

```
import re


def logs():
    logs = []
    w = '(?P<host>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\s+(?:\S+)\s+(?P<user_name>\S+)\s+\[(?P<time>[-+\w\s:/]+)\]\s+"(?P<request>.+?.+?)"'
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as f:
        logdata = f.read()
    for m in re.finditer(w, logdata):
        logs.append(m.groupdict())
    return logs
```

Comment: what do '.+?.+?' mean at the end please?

Comment: here you go my friend
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792851/what-does-mean-in-regex

Answer (score 1):

You're using `\w` to get `user_names`, however `\w` doesn't include `-` that can be in the log ([Common Log Format (CLF)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html)), so as an alternative you could use `\S+` (one or more of anything except a whitespace). For the `time` you can create a capturing group allowing only the expected characters (class) for that field (e.g. `\w\s`, `-+` for the timezone, `/` for the date and `:` for the time) surrounded by squared brackets (literals), a similar capturing can be made for the `request` using `"`.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(
    r'(?P<host>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\s+'
    r'(?:\S+)\s+'
    r'(?P<user_name>\S+)\s+'
    r'\[(?P<time>[-+\w\s:/]+)\]\s+'
    r'"(?P<request>POST.+?)"'
)

def logs():
    data = []
    with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
        logdata = f.read()
    for m in regex.finditer(logdata):
        data.append(m.groupdict())
    return data

print(logs())
```

(*Replaced user_name from first line with "-" for testing on the second line*)

```
[
   {
      "host":"146.204.224.152",
      "user_name":"feest6811",
      "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
      "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/l.l"
   },
   {
      "host":"146.204.224.152",
      "user_name":"-",
      "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
      "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/l.l"
   },
   {
      "host":"144.23.247.108",
      "user_name":"auer7552",
      "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700",
      "request":"POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/l.l"
   },
    ...
```

Comment: That's great it works, but if i want to specify request to print only request:"POST", what should i do?

Comment: @ahmed-sharshar You have to add `POST` to the last capturing group. I edited the answer.

Comment: It seems right, however, some mistake happened using this assert:
```
assert len(logs()) == 979

one_item={'host': '146.204.224.152',
  'user_name': 'feest6811',
  'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
  'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
assert one_item in logs(), "Sorry, this item should be in the log results, check your formating"
```

Comment: @ahmed-sharshar I have edited the question following [Common Log Format (CLF)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) description, see if works now.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(
    r'(?P<host>(?:\d+\.){1,3}\d+)\s+-\s+'
    r'(?P<user_name>[\w+\-]+)?\s+'
    r'\[(?P<time>[-\w\s:/]+)\]\s+'
    r'"(?P<request>\w+.+?)"'
)

def logs():
    data = []
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as f:
        logdata = f.read()
        for item in regex.finditer(logdata):
            x = item.groupdict()
            if x["user_name"] is None:
                x["user_name"] = "-"
            data.append(x)
    return data

logs()
```

Please find below the part of output as well:

[{'host': '146.204.224.152',
'user_name': 'feest6811',
'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'},
{'host': '197.109.77.178',
'user_name': 'kertzmann3129',
'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700',
'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'},
{'host': '156.127.178.177',
'user_name': 'okuneva5222',
'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700',
'request': 'DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1'},
{'host': '100.32.205.59',
'user_name': 'ortiz8891',
'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700',
'request': 'PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0'},
{'host': '168.95.156.240',
'user_name': 'stark2413',
'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700',
'request': 'GET /engage HTTP/2.0'},
.....] with 979 dictionaries for each line of the text file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def logs():
mydata = []
with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
logdata = file.read()
pattern="""
(?P<host>.*)
(\s+)
(?:\S+)
(\s+)
(?P<user_name>\S+)
(\s+)
\[(?P<time>.*)\]\
(\s)
(?P<request>"(.)*")"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
new_item = (item.groupdict())
mydata.append(new_item)
return(mydata)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. Also, indentation is important in Python and this code will generate an `IndentationError`. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re
    def logs():
        with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
            logdata = file.read()

    result = []
    pattern = re.compile(
    r'(?P<host>.*)\s'
    r'(?:-)\s'
    r'(?P<user_name>.*)\s'
    r'\[(?P<time>.*)\]\s'
    r'"(?P<request>.*)"')
    for m in pattern.finditer(logdata):
        data = (m.groupdict())
        result.append(data)
    return result
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit of explanation along with your code to describe why/how it works?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def logs():
with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
    logdata = file.read()   
    lst = []
    for i in re.finditer(r'(?P<host>\S+) - (?P<user_name>\S+) \[(?P<time>.+)\] "(?P<request>.+)"', logdata):
        m = i.groupdict()
        lst.append(m)
    return lst
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also was having trouble with this problem when taking the class, so I thought I'd share what worked for me.

**1)** When defining the host/username/timestamp/request,  look for the bordering characters, like the square brackets [] for the timestamp, or the quotes "" around the request type. As long as the code after the <key> is all-inclusive of the type of text you want to capture, such as alphanumeric, it will capture the desired data. You don't have to try to define it too closely.

EX: I see you have for the username:

```
(?P<user_name>\w*) 
#This includes one character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

But the username may be missing in the data and replaced by a dash - so be sure to include that option! My code:

```
(?P<user_name>[\w-]+)\s 
#This includes 1 or more characters [a-zA-Z0-9_] plus -
```

**2)** For your timestamp and request definitions, you might find it useful to know that `.*?` reads through any amount (`*`) of any character other than a newline (`.`) but in the smallest sequence of characters AKA nongreedy (`?`) so that it doesn't continue past the defined endpoint (such as ] for the timestamp). It's a great way to capture what we need without manually defining every type of character.

```
   \[(?P<time>.*?)\]\s     
   #My timestamp code defining square brackets as the endcaps; 
   #You have to use \[ or \] to refer to the literal character
```

**3)** Don't use print() to return the data at the end. I know it was the example in class. It doesn't work for this problem. You need to produce a list of dictionaries, not one long one. Try appending it! My end code:

```
    loggy=[]  #This creates an empty list 'loggy'
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
        loggy.append(item.groupdict())
        
    return loggy
```

This code appends elements to the list 'loggy': it adds  each iteration to the previous ones. Your function will now produce a LIST of dictionaries which can be searched through as separate elements. It will be an object with length.

I hope this helps anyone reading it!

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
def logs():
    dict=[]
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        pattern="""(?P<host>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
                    (\ - \ )
                    (?P<user_name>(\w*)(\S))
                    (\  \S)
                    (?P<time>\d+\S\w*\S\d+\S\d+\S\d+\S\d+\s\S\d+)
                    (\S\s\S)
                    (?P<request>\w*\s\S*\s\w*\S\d.\d*)
                 """
    
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE): 
        dict.append(item.groupdict())
    return dict 
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

#1 import re module to use regex

#2 define function

#3 open the required file

#4 read the file

#5 write down the pattern of your required string.
For more detailed information regarding regex, read the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).