# What is the difference between d+?\/ and d+\/ in regex?

Tags: regex

What is the difference between `d+?\/` and `d+\/` in regex?

I am studying a project, which I saw this unknown code.

I did a test and used an example of this `dddddddddedd/`, seems both regex take a match

```
dd/
```

so what is the function to add add `?` after `+`???

Comment: Show us a [fiddle](https://regex101.com) link, please. In addition to the regex, typical example input which does or doesn't match would help us to better understand your Use Case.

Comment: duplicates: [What does `+?` mean in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32792851/995714), [Question marks in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5583579/995714), [In a regex, what changes when you add a question mark to `.+`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25528452/995714)